Anchor IDL Init Heap Error?
I get the below message when trying to initialize a new IDL onchain. Have tried mainnet+devnet, a few combos of feature flags on building, several versions of Solana and Anchor. Not sure if anyone has seen this error before, only mention I could find of this heap error was a 2021 PR in solana core.
  Program ComputeBudget111111111111111111111111111111 invoke [1]
  Program ComputeBudget111111111111111111111111111111 success
  Program G2mNHbcwDmnj48HkB1bD8iqhGiourD19DFgM6PxszmeY invoke [1]
  Program G2mNHbcwDmnj48HkB1bD8iqhGiourD19DFgM6PxszmeY consumed 148 of 199850 compute units
  Program G2mNHbcwDmnj48HkB1bD8iqhGiourD19DFgM6PxszmeY failed: Access violation in heap section at address 0x30000ff98 of size 8```


Figured out the issue. I am using the custom-heap allocator and it's screwing up where the IDL build instruction is looking. I added a heap increase instruction to the start of the IDL initialize command and it's working now. Will put a PR up on Anchor.
